# postgresql: when to use array constructor vs curly brackets

Tags: postgresql

I am trying understand why this is a syntax error:

```
SELECT distinct precinct FROM ballots
WHERE code_string = ANY (
  { '20000420300098', '20001240300074'})
```

While this succeeds?

```
SELECT distinct precinct FROM ballots
WHERE code_string = ANY (
  ARRAY[ '20000420300098', '20001240300074'])
```

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces are used in the text representation of arrays.

```
SELECT distinct precinct FROM ballots
WHERE code_string = ANY (
  '{20000420300098,20001240300074}')
```